# Find the solution to and limit of $a_{n+1} =\frac{v}{a_n+w} $ with $a_1>0, v > 0, w>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Find the solution to
and limit of
$a_{n+1}
=\frac{v}{a_n+w}
$
with
$a_1>0, v > 0, w>0$.

This was inspired by
my answer to
[Converging sequence $a_{{n+1}}=6\, \left( a_{{n}}+1 \right) ^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719718/converging-sequence-a-n1-6-left-a-n1-right-1/1719782#1719782).

I will give my answer
in two days.

Comment: You may have noticed that your answer was deleted with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718177/interesting-problem-about-taylor-approximation). Since the questions was reposted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719208/estimating-int-01f-for-an-unknown-lipschitz-f-to-within-0-0001), you can post your answer there (if you wish to do so).

Comment: Sorry for making a comment unrelated to the post - but it is not possible to ping you on a deleted answer. Please, ping me either here or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/3/31) after you read this, so that I can remove these comments (as they will be no longer needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit exists, it must equal $$L = \frac{\sqrt{w^2 + 4v} - w}{2}$$ as we know it satisfies $L^2 + Lw - v = 0$ and $a_1 > 0 , v > 0, w > 0$ .

We now only need to show the sequence convergence. Following Marty Cohen's approach in the special case, we define $a_n = b_n + L$. After some arranging, we have $b_{n+1} = \frac{b_n (w - \sqrt{w^2 + 4v})}{2 b_n + w + \sqrt{w^2 + 4v}}$

Differentiating, we see $$(\frac{x (w - \sqrt{w^2 + 4v})}{2 x + w + \sqrt{w^2 + 4v}})' = - \frac{4v}{(2x + \sqrt{w^2 + 4v} + w)^2}$$
$$= \frac{-v}{(x + L + w)^2}$$

We notice our derivative is less than zero for all x as $v>0$.

Some messy computation follows but all that's left is to bound $b_n$ and show that the bounds become tighter on $b_{n+1}$, leaving us with $|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}| < 1$ for $n \ge c$ where c is some constant.

Comment: Close enough. I am also submitting my own answer, since it goes through with the messy computations without using calculus.

Comment: Yeah though not sure I can call this my work as it severely plagiarizes your proof so I was reluctant to post

Comment: That's OK. My question, my decision. You might like to take a look at my answer here to see some mildly messy algebra.

Answer (score 4):

I was mystified by @Tnilk Imaniq's answer in the linked thread, but then I realized that what he was doing was to set $b_n=1/(a_n+c)$ and then get a linear difference equation for $b_n$. So we do the same:
$$b_n=\frac1{a_n+c};\,\,a_n=\frac1{b_n}-c$$
$$\frac1{b_{n+1}}-c=\frac v{\frac1{b_n}-c+w}=\frac{1-cb_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{vb_n}{1+(w-c)b_n}$$
Clearing denominators,
$$vb_nb_{n+1}=1-cb_{n+1}+(w-c)b_n-c(w-c)b_nb_{n+1}$$
Since all we know is linear difference equations, we demand $c^2-wc-v=0$.
$$c=\frac{w\pm\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2=\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2$$
because we anticipate that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=\infty$$
and we know that $a_n>0$, so we must have $c<0$. Then our linear difference equation is
$$cb_{n+1}+(c-w)b_n=\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2b_{n+1}+\frac{-w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2b_n=1$$
We seek a particular solution $b_{np}=A$, so
$$-A\sqrt{w^2+4v}=1,\,\,b_{np}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{w^2+4v}}$$
Now we solve the homogeneous equation
$$\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2b_{n+1,h}+\frac{-w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2b_{nh}=0$$
This has a solution of the form $b_{nh}=c_1r^k$ if
$$r=\frac{\frac{w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2}{\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2}=\frac{\left(w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}\right)^2}{-4v}$$
so
$$b_n=b_{np}+b_{nh}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{w^2+4v}}+c_1r^n$$
$$b_1=\frac1{a_1+\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{w^2+4v}}+c_1r$$
From which we obtain
$$c_1r=\frac{a_1+\frac{w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2}{\sqrt{w^2+4v}\left(a_1+\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2\right)}$$
So our solution is
$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{w^2+4v}}{-1+\frac{a_1+\frac{w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2}{a_1+\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4v}}2}\left(\frac{\left(w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}\right)^2}{-4v}\right)^{n-1}}-\frac{w-\sqrt{w^2+4}}2$$
Since $|r|>1$, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\frac{\sqrt{w^2+4v}-w}2$$
I see that the OP has posted an answer while I was typing this up even though he said he would give us two days to reply. Oh well...

Comment: That's fine. I upvoted you.

Comment: Perhaps introducing a bit of extra notation could've reduced the amount you had to type, though very nice answer overall

Answer (score 3):

Find the solution to
$a_{n+1}
=\frac{v}{a_n+w}
$
with
$a_1>0, v > 0, w>0$.

My solution:

The limit
$L
=\frac{-w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}}{2}
$.

If
$b_m = a_m-L$,
then

$b_m
=\frac{1}{c_0(-d)^m+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}$

where

$\begin{array}\\
c
&=-1/L\\
d
&=1+w/L=v/L^2\\
c_0
&=\frac1{-db_1}+\frac{c}{d(d+1)}\\
&=\frac1{-d(a_1-L)}+\frac{c}{d(d+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

Since $d > 1$,
as long as $c_0 \ne 0$,
$b_m \to 0$
so that
$a_m \to L$.

Also,
$b_{2m}
=\frac{1}{c_0d^{2m}+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}$
and
$b_{2m+1}
=\frac{1}{-c_0d^{2m+1}+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}$.

Here is what I did.

If it has a limit $L$,
then
$L
=\frac{v}{L+w}
$
or
$L^2+wL-v=0$
or
$L
=\frac{-w\pm\sqrt{w^2+4v}}{2}
$.
To make $L > 0$,
choose
$L
=\frac{-w+\sqrt{w^2+4v}}{2}
$.

Let
$b_n = a_n-L$.
then
$b_{n+1}+L
=\frac{v}{b_n+L+w}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
b_{n+1}
&=\frac{v}{b_n+L+w}-L\\
&=\frac{v-L(b_n+L+w)}{b_n+L+w}\\
&=\frac{v-Lb_n-L^2-wL}{b_n+L+w}\\
&=\frac{-Lb_n}{b_n+L+w}
\qquad\text{since }L^2+wL-v=0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{b_{n+1}}
&=\frac{b_n+L+w}{-Lb_n}\\
&=\frac1{-L}-\frac{L+w}{Lb_n}\\
&=c-\frac{d}{b_n}
\qquad\text{where } c=-1/L, d=1+w/L=v/L^2\\
\text{so}\\
\frac1{d^{n+1}b_{n+1}}
&=\frac{c}{d^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{d^nb_n}\\
\text{or}\\
\frac1{(-d)^{n+1}b_{n+1}}
&=\frac{c}{(-d)^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{(-d)^nb_n}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting
$c_n
=\frac{1}{(-d)^nb_n}
$,
$c_{n+1}
=\frac{c}{(-d)^{n+1}}+c_n
$
where
$c_1
=\frac1{-db_1}
=\frac1{-d(a_1-L)}
$.

Summing from $1$
to $m-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
c_m-c_1
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(c_{n+1}-c_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{c}{(-d)^{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{c}{(-d)^2}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{(-d)^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{c}{d^2}\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\frac{1}{(-d)^{n}}\\
&=\frac{c}{d^2}\frac{1-\frac1{(-d)^{m-1}}}{1-\frac1{-d}}\\
&=\frac{c}{d^2}\frac{1-\frac1{(-d)^{m-1}}}{1+\frac1{d}}\\
&=c\frac{1-\frac1{(-d)^{m-1}}}{d(d+1)}\\
&=c(\frac1{d(d+1)}+\frac1{(-d)^{m}(d+1)})\\
&=\frac{c}{d(d+1)}+\frac{c}{(-d)^{m}(d+1)}\\
\text{or}\\
c_m
&=c_1+\frac{c}{d(d+1)}+\frac{c}{(-d)^{m}(d+1)}\\
&=c_0+\frac{c}{(-d)^{m}(d+1)}
\qquad\text{where }c_0=c_1+\frac{c}{d(d+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
b_m
&=\frac1{(-d)^m}\frac{1}{c_m}\\
&=\frac1{(-d)^m}\frac{1}{c_0+\frac{c}{(-d)^{m}(d+1)}
}\\
&=\frac{1}{c_0(-d)^m+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}\\
\text{so that}\\
b_{2m}
&=\frac{1}{c_0d^{2m}+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}\\
\text{and}\\
b_{2m+1}
&=\frac{1}{-c_0d^{2m+1}+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}\\
\end{array}
$

We have

$\begin{array}\\
c_0
&=c_1+\frac{c}{d(d+1)}\\
&=\frac1{-d(a_1-L)}-\frac{1}{d(d+1)}\\
&=\frac1{-d}(\frac1{a_1-L}+\frac{1}{d+1})\\
&=\frac1{-d(a_1-L)(d+1)}(d+1+a_1-L)\\
&=\frac1{-d(a_1-L)(d+1)}(2+w/L+a_1-L)\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$L^2+wL=v$,
if $c_0 = 0$
then
$a_1
=L-w/L-1
$.

If $|d| > 1$,
which will be true
if $w > 0$,
and $c_0 \ne 0$,
then
$c_m
\to c_0
$
and
$b_m
\approx \frac1{(-d)^mc_0}
\to 0
$
so that
$a_m \to L$.

For the question
that inspired this,
$v=6, w=1$,
so
$L=2$,
so
$c=-\frac12$
and
$d=1+\frac12
=\frac32$
and
$c_1
=\frac1{-d(a_1-L)}
=\frac1{-\frac32(1-2)}
=\frac23
$
so 
$c_0
=\frac23+\frac{-\frac12}{\frac32\frac52}
=\frac23(1-\frac{1}{5})
=\frac{8}{15}
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
b_m
&=\frac{1}{c_0(-d)^m+\frac{c}{(d+1)}
}\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{8}{15}(-\frac32)^m+\frac{-\frac12}{\frac52}
}\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{8}{15}(-\frac32)^m-\frac15}\\
&=\frac{15}{8(-\frac32)^m-3}\\
\text{so that}\\
a_m
&=2+\frac{15}{8(-\frac32)^m-3}\\
&=\frac{15+2(8(-\frac32)^m-3)}{8(-\frac32)^m-3}\\
&=\frac{9+16(-\frac32)^m}{8(-\frac32)^m-3}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that
$b_{2m}
=\frac{15}{8(-\frac32)^{2m}-3}
=\frac{15}{8(\frac94)^{m}-3}
$
and
$b_{2m+1}
=\frac{15}{8(-\frac32)^{2m+1}-3}
=\frac{-15}{8\frac32(\frac94)^{m}+3}
=\frac{-15}{12(\frac94)^{m}+3}
=\frac{-5}{4(\frac94)^{m}+1}
$
so that
$b_{2m}$
is decreasing
and
$b_{2m+1}$
is increasing.

Comment: Much worse than I imagined

Comment: There probably are better ways to do it. That is the way I came up with. The result would be the same, and Mathematica probably uses a variation of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence converges, then the limit $L$ satisfies
$$
L = \frac{v}{L+w} \iff L^2 + Lw -v = 0 \iff L = \frac{-w \pm \sqrt{w^2+4v}}{2}
$$
You are guaranteed the root is real since you are assuming $w >0$ and $v >0$...

Comment: You don't have to assume $w>0$ for the root to be real

Comment: Also you know $L>0$ so if the limit exists it is equal to $L = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{w^2 + 4v} - \frac{w}{2}$

Comment: Prove the sequence converges and I will accept.