# Does $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+\alpha}{x_n+1}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**Problem**
Let $\alpha > 1$. A sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 0} $ is defined such that $x_0 > \sqrt{\alpha}$ and 
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+\alpha}{x_n+1} \ ,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N^0}$$
Does this sequence converge? If so, to what?

*I solved the sum in a way and so want someone to check its validity. If there is error please correct it. And also if there is any other alternate solution please show it. I have attached a link to my solution*:
[My Solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw60kLR_HNOObVBtTjFqdGRTRUFXYUxqVWJ6VDhKVkJRbzlB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: To $\sqrt{\alpha}$

Comment: justify @albo ...

Comment: Your two sequences $E_n$ do converge but not necessarily to $0$.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit plz... I mean $E_n$ was defined as the difference between $x_n -\sqrt{\alpha}$
I understand that the 0 argument is vague but i have a question

Comment: How do you prove that $E_n$ converges to $0$ ?

Comment: Yes i understand ur logic. 

So can i do this:

$E_n$ converges and as a result $x_n$ converges because $\sqrt{\alpha}$ is a constant.
So substituing $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+1} = x_n= L$ and get $L=\sqrt{\alpha}$ ?

Comment: No, $E_n$ needn't converge to $0$.

Comment: So how to show the convergence of $E_n$

Comment: Both $E_n$ converge as monotonic and bounded, no problem.

Comment: They are monotonic and bounded but can converge to different limits i guess....as one is approaching $\sqrt{\alpha}$ from below and other from above....then how to show the limit

Comment: you are talking about a sequence $a_n$ and a sequence $x_n$. Please correct this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that if this sequence does converge, the limit $ x $ satisfies

$$ x(x+1) = x + \alpha $$
$$ x^2 - \alpha = 0 $$

so that if the sequence converges, it can only converge to $ \sqrt{\alpha} $. (The terms are nonnegative.) Now, we show that it converges. Note that

$$ |x_{n+1} - x_n| = \left| \frac{(x_n + \alpha)(x_{n-1} + 1) - (x_{n-1} + \alpha)(x_n + 1)}{(x_n + 1)(x_{n-1} + 1)} \right| = \left| \frac{(x_n - x_{n-1})(1 - \alpha)}{(x_n + 1)(x_{n-1} + 1)} \right| $$

Now, we have the following bound:

$$ (x_n + 1)(x_{n-1} + 1) = x_{n-1} + \alpha + x_{n-1} + 1 > \alpha + 1 $$

therefore

$$ |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \left| \frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha + 1} \right| |x_n - x_{n-1}| $$

This establishes that $ x_n $ is a contractive sequence for $ \alpha > 1 $, therefore it is convergent.

Answer (score 4):

**If** the limit $L$ exist, it will be such that $$L=\frac{L+\alpha}{L+1}$$ Reducing to same denominator $$L^2+L=L+\alpha$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: I have posted the link to my solution in the question. Please check this.
The problem is about study the limit not only evaluating it. So kindly do check my solution.

Comment: @RanojoyDutta You should post that work in the question...

Comment: I think u haven't read the whole question properly. I have given a link to my solution in the question. Please do read it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\alpha\gt1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}
&=\frac{x_n+\alpha}{x_n+1}\\
&=\frac{\alpha-1}{x_n+1}+1\\[6pt]
&\gt1\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Iterating the recursion, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+2}
&=\frac{\frac{x_n+\alpha}{x_n+1}+\alpha}{\frac{x_n+\alpha}{x_n+1}+1}\\
&=\frac{x_n+\alpha+\alpha(x_n+1)}{x_n+\alpha+x_n+1}\\
&=\frac{x_n(\alpha+1)+2\alpha}{2x_n+(\alpha+1)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $x_n\gt1$, if we subtract $\sqrt\alpha$ from $(2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,x_{n+2}-\sqrt\alpha\,\right|
&=\left|\,\frac{x_n(\alpha-2\sqrt\alpha+1)-\sqrt\alpha(\alpha-2\sqrt\alpha+1)}{2x_n+(\alpha+1)}\,\right|\\[3pt]
&=\left|\,x_n-\sqrt\alpha\,\right|\frac{(\alpha+1)-2\sqrt\alpha}{(\alpha+1)+2x_n}\\[3pt]
&\le\left|\,x_n-\sqrt\alpha\,\right|\color{#C00000}{\frac{(\alpha+1)-2\sqrt\alpha}{(\alpha+1)+2}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since $0\lt\frac{\left(\sqrt\alpha-1\right)^2}{\alpha+3}=\color{#C00000}{\frac{(\alpha+1)-2\sqrt\alpha}{(\alpha+1)+2}}=1-2\frac{\sqrt\alpha+1}{\alpha+3}\lt1$,
inequality $(3)$ says that both even and odd indices converge to $\sqrt\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

This recurrence relation looked familiar, and sure enough [I showed how to solve this class of problem earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1720950/316404). First we rewrite as
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+\alpha}{x_n+1}=1+\frac{\alpha-1}{x_n+1}$$
So now we let $y_n=x_n-1$ and we have
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha-1}{y_n+2}$$
Now the trick that works is
$$z_n=\frac1{y_n+c}$$
Where $c$ is to be determined. Then $y_n=1/z_n-c$ and
$$\frac1{z_{n+1}}-c=\frac{\alpha-1}{\frac1{z_n-c+2}}=\frac{1-cz_{n+1}}{z_{n+1}}=\frac{(\alpha-1)z_n}{1+(2-c)z_n}$$
Clearing denominators,
$$(\alpha-1)z_nz_{n+1}=1-cz_{n+1}+(2-c)z_n-c(2-c)z_nz_{n+1}$$
We can eliminate the nonlinear term if $c^2-2c-\alpha+1=0$, so $c=1\pm\sqrt{1+\alpha-1}=1-\sqrt{\alpha}$ so as to make $z_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then we have a linear difference equation with constant coefficients,
$$(1-\sqrt{\alpha})z_{n+1}-(1+\sqrt{\alpha})z_n=1$$
The homogeneous difference equation is
$$(1-\sqrt{\alpha})z_{h,n+1}-(1+\sqrt{\alpha})z_{h,n}=0$$
Letting $z_{h,n}=r^n$ we derive the characteristic equation
$$(1-\sqrt{\alpha})r-(1+\sqrt{\alpha})=0$$
So the solution to the homogeneous equation is
$$z_{h,n}=K\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\alpha}}{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^2$$
And trying a constant solution we find soon enough that
$$z_{p,n}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}$$
is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous difference equation. Thus the general solution is
$$z_n=z_{p,n}+z_{h,n}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}+K\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\alpha}}{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^2$$
Applying initial conditions,
$$z_0=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}+K=\frac1{y_0+1-\sqrt{\alpha}}=\frac1{x_0-\sqrt{\alpha}}$$
So
$$K=\frac1{x_0-\sqrt{\alpha}}+\frac1{2\sqrt{\alpha}}=\frac{x_0+\sqrt{\alpha}}{2\sqrt{\alpha}\left(x_0-\sqrt{\alpha}\right)}$$
$$z_n=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}+K\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\alpha}}{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^n$$
Working back to the start,
$$x_n=\frac1{\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}+K\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\alpha}}{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)^n}+\sqrt{\alpha}$$
Since $\alpha>1$, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{1+\sqrt{\alpha}}{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}\right|^n=\infty$$
So
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\sqrt{\alpha}$$
Perhaps a little more long-winded, but we were able to derive an expression for $x_n$.

Comment: Definitely way more work than needed! I've never seen the difference equation methods, but this is pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried putting my formulas into a spreadsheet and they failed. Thus I have edited my answer to insert corrected formulas that now pass the spreadsheet test.

Comment: Is this a standard technique for difference equations? It's seems similar to variation of parameters for differential equations, solving for the homogenous and particular solutions.

Comment: A linear difference equation is much like a linear differential equation in that superposition works, but I'm not sure about the variation of parameters part.